# Laravel store secure password and authenticate

Tags: php, laravel-5

2 and I am having a problem while i register and login a user.
I worked on codeigniter as following code has been used to store password and hash:

```
array('user_login_salt' => md5($time_now),'user_login_password' => md5(md5(md5($time_now) . $password)),
    'user_password_hash' => $this->encrypt->encode($password, md5(md5(md5($time_now) . $password))),
    'user_security_hash' => md5($time_now . $password))
```

and when i log in the use then check the password as per condition as follows:

```
md5(md5(strtolower($this->encrypt->decode($user_details_array['user_password_hash'], $user_details_array['user_login_password']))))=== $user_password..
```

Now in laravel I want to do the exact same thing for register a user and user login. What i need exactly is i need to store user login salt, user login password, user password hash and user security hash. Security hash must be 32 character long exactly..
So please looking for any solution which registers the user in the same way and login by user_password_hash...
Thank you

Comment: md5 is not a secure password hashing algorithm. Please consider using https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and migrating your existing users' passwords (you can hash the current password md5s and set a flag until the user logs in next, then hash the user's entered password directly and store it)

Comment: Hi @jedifans i want to generate password hash based on key. So that i can login easily.

Comment: Define "key"? The code you have posted is using an insecure algorithm for password storage. Use the built-in secure methods instead of rolling your own, for your users' sake and your company's reputation.

Comment: I have just done the algo and used Hash::make method...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1: Use Laravel build-in auth for login, logout** 
*- In Console run*

```
php artisan make:auth
```

This command creates *users table*, *UserController* and *User Model*. Now you can access yoururl/login,..etc
**Solution 2: Handle manually with Hash in Laravel**. Ex: In Controller 
*- Hash password*

```
$hashedPassword = \Hash::make($password);
```

*- Compare password*

```
// Return true if password matches hash
$check = \Hash::check('plain-text-password', $hashedPassword)
```

Comment: Hi @KmasterYC thank you for your valuable answer. But I am not using built in system. I am creating myself for login and register and i want to generate password hash based on key. So that i can login easily.